# Limit the upper predicted values in r

Tags: r, regression, prediction, lm

I'm trying to predict rainfall. But the log model gives very high prediction for certain values. Please check the plot for actual vs predicted values. Is it possible to limit/restrict the upper predicted values?

```
// This is a two-part model. So First im predicting rain or no rain (0,1) 
// using logistic regression then using lm model to predict the quantity of rain
mod_LR=glm( Rainfall_LR ~ ., data = train_main[,-8]  , family = binomial(link = logit),offset = Pressure)

phat <- predict(mod_LR,test_main , type = "response")
pred <- data.frame(test_main)
logols.fit <- lm(log(Rainfall_Next3)~., train_main[train_main$Rainfall_Next3 > 0, -9])

pred$logols <- phat * exp(predict(logols.fit, test_main))
```

[image: Actual Vs Predicted Values]

Comment: Is this from a linear model? Can you show your code?

Comment: @user2974951 I have added code. This is a two-point model. Modeling a different rainfall response with binary first, and then modeling a different rainfall response with lm for predicting non-zero values

Comment: Try a 1 point model  ..to predict rain directly . Post your data and I will try and help further .

Comment: Two-part model is more commonly used jargon in what I see.

Comment: Or 'mixture model'

Comment: It is a little strange to attempt to model the logarithm of rainfall, because in most places on earth there are plenty of times of year when no rainfall occurs.  You could therefore interpret the problematically high predictions as a symptom of an incorrect model, suggesting you wouldn't want to paper over that problem simply by limiting the sizes of the predictions: you would want to develop a better model altogether.